# Comprimo una imagen y luego se ve mas pequeña

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una clase para guardar las imagenes que hago por camara, el problema es que luego me aparecen mas pequeñas.

```
public class saveImages {

private Context TheThis;
private String NameOfFolder = "/Aplicacion";
private String NameOfFile = "image";

public Uri SaveImage(Context context, Bitmap ImageToSave) {

    TheThis = context;
    //el nombre de la carpeta
    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + NameOfFolder;
    String CurrentDateAndTime = getCurrentDateAndTime();
    File dir = new File(file_path);



    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    //Creamos el archivo de la imagen
    File file = new File(dir, NameOfFile + CurrentDateAndTime + ".jpg");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(file);
        AbleToSave();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        UnableToSave();
    }


    return Uri.fromFile(file);
}

private void MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(File file) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(TheThis,
            new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                }
            });
}
```

Esa es la clase para guardar la imagen, utilizo este metodo para cargar la imagen y guardarla.

```
public Uri cargarImagenCamara(Intent data) {

    if (data != null) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            save = new saveImages();
            imageUri = save.SaveImage(comida2.this, imageBitmap);
            return imageUri;
        }
    }
    imageUri = null;
    return null;
}
```

Y esto para cargarla en el image:

```
    public void redimenImagenCamara(Uri imageUri) {

            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(imageUri)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .into(foto1);

}
```

EDITO:  Añado los ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/foto1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_add_a_photo_black_36dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/foto2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_add_a_photo_black_36dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/foto3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_add_a_photo_black_36dp" />
```

La idea es que al añadir la foto aparezca como en miniatura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa las propiedades del `ImageView` donde cargas la imagen que es `foto1` :

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageUri)
            .asBitmap()
            .into(foto1);
```

Tu puedes cambiar sus dimensiones para desplegar en pantalla con un tamaño mayor, para esto modifica su alto y ancho definiendo un tamaño en `dp` o usa `match_parent` :

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

---

Por otro lado te recomiendo aumentes la calidad de tu imagen, **esto no afecta la medida**, pero se tendrá una mejor calidad de la misma:

```
  //Segundo parametro es calidad 0 - 100 %
  ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fOut);
```

como ejemplo un bitmap con 0% de calidad:

```
ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, fOut);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la misma imagen con 80% de calidad:

```
ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fOut);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Actualización:

Como te he comentado, el archivo salvado no debe tener diferencia en tamaño, lo que provoca se vea más pequeño es el contenedor.

Estas usando un `ImageButton` que ademas tiene un margen y un peso de 25 por lo que se mostraría en este porcentaje en la pantalla, por lo cual es obvio se vea más pequeño.

Considero que deberias de usar un `ImageView`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, es que cuando añado por camara que es cuando hago las funciones que pongo arriba se ve mas pequeño, debe ser algun problema al guardar la imagen pero es que no lo veo. He añadido alguna información más a ver si alguien lo ve más claro.

Comment: Puedes agregar una imagen de como se ve originalmente y como se ve mas pequeño?. Si el contenedor tiene margen y ademas un tamano proporcional en relación a los demás elementos en la pantalla, es obvio se vería más pequeño que cuando aparece en la camara y cubre toda la mayoría de espacio en la pantalla en la prevista de la camara. Revisa mi actualizaciòn.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando la comprimes de esta manera

```
ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, fOut);
```

Le estás indicando que la calidad con la que quieres comprimir la imagen es 0 (lo que supone muy poca calidad para la imagen). Ponle 100 para ver si el tamaño que de la imagen al descomprimir es el mismo, luego puedes ir jugando con este valor hasta que se adecue a lo que estás buscando.

```
ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
```

Comment: La calidad solo implica cambio del tamano en bytes no en dimensiones.

Comment: Si la comprimes todo lo pisible y pierdes bytes luego no los puedes recuperar, no puede salir la misma imagen al descomprimirla (diría yo)